# Showing Chinese character '稳' in python wordcloud

Tags: python, word-cloud

The character '稳' isn't showing when I try to do a wordcloud.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

    d={'稳' : 2,
       '定' : 3,
       '稳增长' : 4,
       '国企' : 4}

    wc = WordCloud(font_path=font_path, background_color="white", width=1000, height=860)
    
    wen = wc.generate_from_frequencies(d)
    
    plt.figure()
    
    plt.imshow(wen)
    plt.axis("off")
```

Produces this, 稳 has disappeared

[image]

If I replace 稳 with 快 it works fine

```
d={'快' : 2,
   '定' : 3,
   '快增长' : 4,
   '国企' : 4}

wc = WordCloud(font_path=font_path, background_color="white", width=1000, height=860)

kuai = wc.generate_from_frequencies(d)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(kuai)
plt.axis("off")
```

[image]

I must be doing something wrong, but can't work out what.

Comment: Does your font have a glyph for `稳`?

Answer (score 1):

I am using WordCloud version 1.8.2.2. Here is my code and it works:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

words={
    '稳'     : 2,
    '定'     : 3,
    '稳增长' : 4,
    '国企'   : 4
    }

# The font is taken from
# https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/raw/master/examples/fonts/SourceHanSerif/SourceHanSerifK-Light.otf 
wc = WordCloud(
    font_path='./SourceHanSerifK-Light.otf',
    background_color="white",
    width=1000,
    height=860
    )

wen = wc.generate_from_frequencies(words)
wc.to_file('./wc.jpg')
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks and to @user2357112. I changed the font library from PingFang to songti, and now it works.